# Questions about LISP

Tags: lisp, racket

I am learning LISP by using Racket!
I have problem in solving these three question.

1) (banana in (Jane has a backyard))

2) (banana and Jane)

3) (((banana) and ((Jane))) in her backyard)

In the form of the list above, how can I get only Jane? (using car/cdr)

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Interactions window in DrRacket and play around with applying various combinations of `car` and `cdr` to each list.

Example:

```
> (car '(banana in (Jane has a backyard)))
'banana
> (cdr '(banana in (Jane has a backyard)))
'(in (Jane has a backyard))
> (car (cdr '(banana in (Jane has a backyard))))
'in
> (cdr (cdr '(banana in (Jane has a backyard))))
'((Jane has a backyard))
> (cdr (cdr (cdr '(banana in (Jane has a backyard)))))
'()
> (car (cdr (cdr '(banana in (Jane has a backyard)))))
'(Jane has a backyard)
```

I'm pretty sure that you can take over from here...